# Create an action which stops the iPhone lockscreen from going to sleep whilst typing inside a provided input

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, shortcut

I have a shortcut which appends text to a .md note in my files app, I want to be able to use this shortcut quickly from the lockscreen. However, whenever I type the phone doesn't register that I'm typing, and the screen falls asleep, meaning I can only type so many words before it locks again.

How can I create an action/shortcut to be able to stop the device from falling asleep on the lockscreen, or at least check that I am typing so that it doesn't lock.

Comment: I don’t know if this was intentional on Apple’s part, but allowing text entry on a lock screen seems like a potential security vulnerability (at least a vector).  Either way, this appears to be a UI limitation and not something that can be user configured